# 'could not load module' after install from powershell

Tags: python, windows, powershell, pip, pycharm

After installing `mediapipe` using windows power shell I tried to import module in my python project in Pycharm project using the code `import mediapipe as mp` and I got the got the following error in python console

```
 C:\Python37\python.exe C:/Users/Vivek/PycharmProjects/artifix/main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vivek\PycharmProjects\artifix\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import mediapipe as mp
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from mediapipe.python import *
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from mediapipe.python._framework_bindings import resource_util
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _framework_bindings: The specified module could not be found.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Try to call the same file with `python3 main.py`

Comment: Run pip list command and check whether mediapipe is exist

Comment: @YJR it exists i checked

Comment: Try another version of module may be work

Comment: @YJR tried all even searched on internet if some are left